# Getting region id on onestepcheckout page

Tags: payment-gateway, onepage-checkout

I want to get region id on onestepcheckout ajax page on payment_method template when it is refreshed. I want to hide credit card for some regions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the selected billing region:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getRegionId();
```

And for shipping region:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegionId();
```